# If condition always returning true

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, explode

I am reading a text file line by line and each line has comma separated values. example

```
Name,Phone,URL,notavailable
```

The reading is fine and the script returns the lines correctly. The last value has "available" or "notavailable".

I am exploding a line like this

```
$sections = explode(",", $line);
```

and it returns

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Name
        [1] => Phone
        [2] => URL
        [3] => notavailable

    )
```

I can get values using

```
$sections[0], $sections[1] etc.
```

And they display just fine. But the problem occurs when I try to compare the last value.

```
$check = $sections[3];
if($check=="notavailable")
{Do something }
else {Do something else}
```

But the if statement always returns false. I could not figure that out. Tried so many time. It will be so much helpful somebody can point out the error in my script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a little debugging. Throw in a line like

```
$check = $sections[3];
echo "check = '$check'";    // Debug print
```

If you print it out in quotes like that, you'll probably see there are leading/trailing spaces. If that is the case, a simple call to [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

$a == $b    Equal   TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

When you read file, you also read spaces, so you need to trim them.

So you should use:

```
if(trim($section[3]) === "notavailable"){
    //Do something
} else {
    //Do something else
}
```

Comment: I don't really think `===` is appropriate here.

Comment: Even without `===` you need to use `trim` function to remove whitespaces as your `$section[3]` can contain whitespace which you don`t need.

Comment: Right. Which is why I stated that in my answer. I'm not sure what that has to do with `===`.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 if(preg_match_all('/notavailable/i',$section[3]))
 {
    // Not Available
 }
 else
 {
     // Available
 }
```